# Is there a key shortcut to stop automatic closure of brackets?

Tags: python, django, autocomplete, pycharm, closures

I'm currently playing around with Django using PyCharm and have never used this IDE for Django development before as I usually just used Visual Studio Code or Atom etc. PyCharm has a useful feature for auto closing brackets and expressions, for example, if I type `'{%'`, it will produce `'{% %}'` with my cursor in the middle. The problem is *sometimes* I might not want this to happen say, if I'm editing code rather than writing it.

What I'm wondering is, is there a way to temporarily override this feature by pressing a key? I don't want to disable the feature entirely as it is otherwise useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the Smart Keys settings, and uncheck the box labeled "Insert Pair Bracket".

[image: Settings]

This can disable it entirely, but there isn't a built-in way to disable it with a keyboard shortcut.  There could be an extension that would do that.